# What is the syntax to query a raster layer in ArcGIS Server?

Tags: raster, arcgis-server, arcgis-rest-api, spatial-query

I'm familiar with querying a **feature layer** in the ArcGIS Server REST API, for example including a `where` clause, specifying the desired output fields, choosing whether or not to return the geometry:

https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/USA/MapServer/3/query?where=name+like+%27A%25%27&outFields=name%2C+state_name%2C+pop2000&returnGeometry=false&f=pjson

What is the correct syntax for querying a **raster layer**? For example, this sample layer supports the query interface:

https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Elevation/GlacierBay/MapServer/0/query

but I can't figure out the correct input parameters to return any values.

My goal is to supply an input polygon and retrieve the values of the raster cells found within it.

Sample query: https://sampleserver6.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/Elevation/GlacierBay/MapServer/0/query?f=json&geometry=%7B%22spatialReference%22%3A%7B%22latestWkid%22%3A3857%2C%22wkid%22%3A102100%7D%2C%22xmin%22%3A-15242064.27528213%2C%22ymin%22%3A8068597.150135476%2C%22xmax%22%3A-15236646.800902426%2C%22ymax%22%3A8076298.180735197%7D&outFields=*&spatialRel=esriSpatialRelIntersects&where=1%3D1&geometryType=esriGeometryEnvelope&inSR=102100&outSR=102100

returns `Invalid or missing input parameters`. How should I format this query to return the raster values within the input polygon?

Comment: I doubt you can query feature values for a raster through a MapServer. It's like asking how many cubic centimeters are in an electric engine. You can write a GP service or SOE to return what you want.

Comment: @Vince yeah I was surprised to even see that a raster layer has a query endpoint - but since it exists, and the layer reports `"capabilities": "Map,Query"` there must be a way to use it. Even if it doesn't solve my issue I'm keen to find out how to use this query interface